# ROS/ROS 2 on non-ubuntu platforms

Tags: fedora, ros

I was thinking to learn ROS and I realized that officially ROS only supports ubuntu. I am habitual with another Linux distribution, i.e. Fedora.

So I was wanting to know, that if I install ROS on fedora(which is listed as experimental by the community). Will it work as smoothly and with all available resources/packages/options or not?

Also, the ROS 2 Foxy Fitzro is available on windows, is it fine to use that? or I might some lack of support?
I read somewhere that ROS on other platforms doesn't have all packages and similar problems

Comment: I highly recommend using Ubuntu to have access to as much support as possible, especially if you're just getting started with ROS. You could have a lot of problems just doing the install for ROS/ROS2, but in my experience the ubuntu versions are more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Some packages used in ROS are not currently available in the Fedora RPM repositories. Most of the other packages are available in RPM Fusion.Please see [RPM Fusion Command Line Setup](https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration#Command_Line_Setup_using_rpm).

> the ROS 2 Foxy Fitzro is available on windows, is it fine to use that?

Yes, ROS 2 Foxy Fitzro is available on windows, but the pre-built binary does not include all ROS 2 packages. All packages in the ROS base variant are included, and only a subset of packages in the ROS desktop variant are included.

Answer (score 0):

This answer concerns only the Fedora section. It works on Fedora 33.

I am not a ROS expert so I can't answer this question:

> Will it work **as smoothly** and with **all** available resources/packages/options or not?

But I prefer not to be too optimist. If you only want to test ROS it might be fine. But if you are looking for a production development, you should better use Ubuntu instead of losing time to tweak ROS for Fedora compatibility.

However, it is possible to run ROS on Fedora. I was able to run the `demo_nodes_py` in `talker` and `listener` mode. This is the ROS hello world.

## Build the source

There is no package to install ROS in one simple command nor I was able to run the CentOS "fat archive". I got errors, I didn't invest more than 15 minutes to solve them. Information on the internet was poor.

The only solution I found so far is to build ROS from the source. The operation was not complex as it is fully documented: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Foxy/Fedora-Development-Setup/

Note that it took around 2 hours to compile.

Be aware that the compilation might require lots of skills especially when it fails.

## Virtualization

Those solutions should even work with other Linux distributions.

### Use Docker

You can download this image: https://hub.docker.com/_/ros

If you have already installed Docker and you are familiar with it, it seems a fair solution. It works out of the box and the image webpage is fully documented.

Thanks to the docker volumes, it is possible to develop the code and read the logs from withing your Fedora environment and to run the ROS application within the debian container.

Also, you can connect the containers to your system localhost (on Fedora). It allows to send and receive messages. As an example, I was able to interact in those 2 contexts:

1. `talker (Docker)` <-> `Listener (Fedora from source)`
2. `talker (Fedora from source)` <-> `Listener (Docker)`.

### Use a Virtual Machine on Ubuntu

This sounds the safer way to use the full potential of ROS. But a VM will require more disk space, more computation and you should learn the Ubuntu style to work within the VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it for simple level operations without any problems, but when it comes to more specific issues you are very likely to run into weird problems. The solutions to these problems can be very complex. So it would be much safer to download it to ubuntu somehow.